# Modifying previously set CSS style of JEditorPane

Tags: java, css, swing

How do I modify CSS style of JEditorPane. I set style like this (and it works):

```
StyleSheet styleSheet = new StyleSheet();
styleSheet.addRule("body {font-family:"Arial"; font-size:12; } ");

HTMLEditorKit hTMLEditorKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
hTMLEditorKit.setStyleSheet(styleSheet);

JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");
editorPane.setEditorKit(messageEditorPaneHTMLEditorKit);
```

Now, I would like to modify that style (set different font in this case). I tried this, but it does nothing. Styles remain unchanged.

```
Style style = hTMLEditorKit.getStyleSheet().getRule("body");
style.addAttribute("font-family", "Helvetica");
style.addAttribute("font-size", 14);
```

How do I modify the style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify a `Style` using `StyleConstants`, which has the added benefit of providing the properties you can modify reducing the dependency on string literals such as `"font-size"`

For example, you could modify:

```
style.addAttribute("font-family", "Helvetica");
style.addAttribute("font-size", 14);
```

to:

```
StyleConstants.setFontSize(style, 14);
StyleConstants.setFontFamily(style, "Helvetica");
```

If you use the `printStyleAttributes` method I've included below, you will see that the changes are now reflected in the `Style`. However this won't automatically apply the changes to your editor pane

In order for the styling changes to be reflected you need to use [`setCharacterAttributes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultStyledDocument.html#setCharacterAttributes(int,%20int,%20javax.swing.text.AttributeSet,%20boolean)) on your document, providing where it should apply from and whether it should override/replace any existing styles found

E.g: `document.setCharacterAttributes(0, document.getLength(), style, true);`

Will update the entire document, replacing styles with the changes

---

SSCCE:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class EditorStylingExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StyleSheet styleSheet = new StyleSheet();
        styleSheet.addRule("body {font-family:\"Arial\"; font-size:12; } ");

        HTMLEditorKit messageEditorPaneHTMLEditorKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
        messageEditorPaneHTMLEditorKit.setStyleSheet(styleSheet);
        HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument) messageEditorPaneHTMLEditorKit.createDefaultDocument();

        JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");
        editorPane.setEditorKit(messageEditorPaneHTMLEditorKit);
        editorPane.setDocument(document);

        JButton changeStyleButton = new JButton("Change style");
        changeStyleButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            Style style = styleSheet.getStyle("body");
            StyleConstants.setBold(style, true);
            StyleConstants.setFontSize(style, 14);
            StyleConstants.setFontFamily(style, "Helvetica");
            printStyleAttributes(style);
            document.setCharacterAttributes(0, document.getLength(), style, true);
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Styling example");
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        contentPane.add(editorPane);
        contentPane.add(changeStyleButton);

        editorPane.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        changeStyleButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void printStyleAttributes(Style style) {
        Enumeration styleAttributes = style.getAttributeNames();
        while (styleAttributes.hasMoreElements()) {
            Object attribute = styleAttributes.nextElement();
            String attributeName = attribute.toString();
            Object attributeValue = style.getAttribute(attribute);
            System.out.println(attributeName + ": " + attributeValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! this helped me greatly. Thanks! StyleConstants.setFontSize(style, 14); Doesn't set the font size to 14 though, it seems to set it to 5 or 6 for some reason.

Comment: Glad to hear :) The value you've provided is still there in the background, you can confirm this with  `System.out.println(StyleConstants.getFontSize(style));` The lower value comes from the deviation from the smallest supported font-size of 8, which is 1 in the output